# Terraform, dynamic attach multiple disk to 1 vps

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

My problem is that I can't dynamically connect the created disks to the vps. The google_compute_disk_attach module cannot be used
Here is my code
What is the correct way in this situation?

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "vps" {
  name                = var.server_name
  description         = var.server_description
  machine_type        = var.server_type
  zone                = var.server_datacenter
  deletion_protection = var.server_delete_protection
  labels              = var.server_labels
  metadata            = var.server_metadata
  tags                = var.server_tags

  boot_disk {
    auto_delete = false
    initialize_params {
      size   = var.boot_volume_size
      type   = var.boot_volume_type
      image  = var.boot_volume_image
      labels = var.boot_volume_labels
    }
  }
  dynamic "attached_disk" {
    for_each = { for vol in var.volumes : vol.volume_name => vol }
    content {
      source = element(var.volumes[*].volume_name, 0)
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    subnetwork = var.server_network

    access_config {
      nat_ip = google_compute_address.static_ip.address
    }
  }
```

```
resource "google_compute_disk" "volume" {
  for_each = { for vol in var.volumes : vol.volume_name => vol }
  name     = each.value.volume_name
  type     = each.value.volume_type
  size     = each.value.volume_size
  zone     = var.server_datacenter
  labels   = each.value.volume_labels
}
```

volumes variables

```
  volumes = [{
    volume_name = "v3-postgres-saga-import-test-storage"
    volume_size = "40"
    volume_type = "pd-ssd"
    volume_labels = {
      environment = "production"
      project     = "v3"
      type        = "storage"
    }
    }, {
    volume_name = "volume-vpstest2"
    volume_size = "20"
    volume_type = "pd-ssd"
    volume_labels = {
      environment = "production"
      project     = "v2"
      type        = "storage"
    }
  }]
```

if do something like that - error

```
source = google_compute_disk.volume[*].self_link
```

This object does not have an attribute named "self_link".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the `volume` variable directly as `map` instead of `Array` :

`variables.tf` file :

```
variable "volumes" {
  default = {
     postgres_saga = {
       volume_name   = "v3-postgres-saga-import-test-storage"
       volume_size   = "40"
       volume_type   = "pd-ssd"
       volume_labels = {
         environment = "production"
         project     = "v3"
         type        = "storage"
       }
    },
    volume_vpstest2 = {
      volume_name   = "volume-vpstest2"
      volume_size   = "20"
      volume_type   = "pd-ssd"
      volume_labels = {
        environment = "production"
        project     = "v2"
        type        = "storage"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of variable, you can also use a local variable from json configuration. Example of structure of `Terraform` module :

```
project
  module
      main.tf
      locals.tf
      resource
          volumes.json
```

`volumes.json` file

```json
{
  "volumes": {
      "postgres_saga" : {
         "volume_name"   : "v3-postgres-saga-import-test-storage"
         "volume_size"   : "40"
         "volume_type"   : "pd-ssd"
         "volume_labels" : {
           "environment" : "production"
           "project"     : "v3"
           "type"        : "storage"
         }
      },
      "volume_vpstest2" : {
        "volume_name"   : "volume-vpstest2"
        "volume_size"   : "20"
        "volume_type"   : "pd-ssd"
        "volume_labels" : {
          "environment" : "production"
          "project"     : "v2"
          "type"        : "storage"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

`locals.tf` file

```
locals {
  tables = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/resource/volumes.json"))["volumes"]
}
```

`main.tf` file :

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "vps" {
  name                = var.server_name
  description         = var.server_description
  machine_type        = var.server_type
  zone                = var.server_datacenter
  deletion_protection = var.server_delete_protection
  labels              = var.server_labels
  metadata            = var.server_metadata
  tags                = var.server_tags

  boot_disk {
    auto_delete = false
    initialize_params {
      size   = var.boot_volume_size
      type   = var.boot_volume_type
      image  = var.boot_volume_image
      labels = var.boot_volume_labels
    }
  }

  dynamic "attached_disk" {
    for_each = [
      var.volumes
      # local.volumes
    ]
    content {
      source = attached_disk.value["volume_name"]
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    subnetwork = var.server_network

    access_config {
      nat_ip = google_compute_address.static_ip.address
    }
  }
}

resource "google_compute_disk" "volume" {
  for_each = var.volumes
  # local.volumes
  name     = each.value["volume_name"]
  type     = each.value["volume_type"]
  size     = each.value["volume_size"]
  zone     = var.server_datacenter
  labels   = each.value["volume_labels"]
}
```

With a `map`, you can directly use `foreach` without any transformation on `google_compute_disk/volume` resource.

You can also use this map in a `dynamic` bloc.

Comment: Doesnt work:

│   on ../module/resource.tf line 25, in resource "google_compute_instance" "vps":
│   25:       source = attached_disk.value["volume_name"]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ attached_disk.value is map of object with 2 elements
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value

Comment: But it works like that only for 1 disk
    content {
      source = attached_disk.value.postgres_saga["volume_name"]
    }

Comment: I edited my answer for the volumes `var`. I also proposed you a another approach with `json` configuration and local variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've used `for_each` in `google_compute_disk.volume`, it will be a **map**, not a list. Thus you can list all `self_link` as follows:

```
source = values(google_compute_disk.volume)[*].self_link
```

Comment: got it
any way how i should dynamic attach disk to vps ?